# How to get field lists from model object in stream and map to another model object?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to get the field list from the list of model object using the stream and map to another list of object but it giving me the below error.

[image]

```
List<FinalTestModel> testModels2 = new ArrayList<>();
testModels2 =     testModels.parallelStream().filter(item -> 
item.getReceiverPtyId().equalsIgnoreCase("TestId"))
            .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getMonthM(),  e.getRecevingAmount(), e.getRecevingCurrency(),
                e.getBTransactionCount())).collect(Collectors.toList());


Input = [TestModel(monthM=May, receiverName=A, receiverC=India, recevingAmount=0.00000, recevingCurrency=KRW, bTransactionCount=1, transactionCount=0), TestModel(monthM=June, receiverName=A, receiverC=India, recevingAmount=10.00000, recevingCurrency=KRW, bTransactionCount=2, transactionCount=0), TestModel(monthM=July, receiverName=A, receiverC=India, recevingAmount=0.00000, recevingCurrency=KRW, bTransactionCount=0, transactionCount=0))]
Expected Output Result = [FinalTestModel(monthM=May, recevingAmount=0.00000, recevingCurrency=KRW, bTransactionCount=1), FinalTestModel(monthM=June, recevingAmount=10.00000, recevingCurrency=KRW, bTransactionCount=2),FinalTestModel(monthM=July, recevingAmount=10.00000, recevingCurrency=KRW, bTransactionCount=10)]
```

Comment: can you show some input and output example

Comment: You need to use `.map(testModel -> new FinalTestModel..)` instead of `flatMap`.

Comment: @Deadpool I have updated my question with input and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating stream of model attributes instead of model object. Creating instance of FinalTestModel should solve this:

```
testModels2 =     testModels.parallelStream()
    .filter(item -> item.getReceiverPtyId().equalsIgnoreCase("TestId"))
    .map(e -> new FinalTestModel(e.getMonthM(), e.getRecevingAmount(), e.getRecevingCurrency(), e.getBTransactionCount()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`flatMap(... Stream.of(new FinalTestModel(...)))` would make sense if you wanted to construct multiple objects. But here it's only single one.

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work

```
testModels2 =     testModels.parallelStream()
.filter(item -> item.getReceiverPtyId().equalsIgnoreCase("TestId"))
.map(e -> new FinalTestModel(....))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```